# Schema.org caption inside Article?

Tags: images, schema.org, microdata

Ho to use Schema.org in the caption of an image?

I see that caption is not present in `BlogPosting` nor [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article).  I made a search and it seems that it is in [`ImageObject`](https://schema.org/ImageObject).

But if I am inside `itemscope` `Article`, can I use `itemprop="caption"`? I mean, can I use the code example below?

```html
<div itemprop="caption">Caption of the image</div>
```

If not, how to use caption inside `Article` or `BlogPosting`?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

<img itemprop="image" src="1.png">
<div>Caption of the image</div>
<h1 itemprop="headline name" >Title of the post</h1>
<div itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-01-07" >2016-01-07</div>
<div itemprop="articleBody" >       
    <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</div>

</div><!-- end schema Article -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) item, and you have to add the [`caption`](http://schema.org/caption) to this `ImageObject` item. Otherwise you would add the `caption` to the `Article`, which is not what you want (and `caption` isn’t defined for `Article` anyway).

So in Microdata it could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

  <!-- Article properties here -->

  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <!-- ImageObject properties here -->
    <p itemprop="caption">Caption of the image</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Article properties here -->

</div>
```

Comment: I find confusing that there is an itemprop="image" in Article. So I can use it there.

Comment: @Nrc: What do you find confusing about this exactly? The `image` property in an `Article` item adds an image of the article. Where else should the `image` be?

Comment: In your code it seems that itemprop caption is a subclass inside itemprop image. But in schema image and caption are at the same level: https://schema.org/ImageObject

Comment: @Nrc: `itemprop` is for adding properties (like `image`, `caption`), not classes (like `Article`, `ImageObject`). In my example, the `Article` item has one property (`image`), which has an `ImageObject` item as value. This `ImageObject` has also one property (`caption`), which has text as value. -- If you would add an `image` property to the `ImageObject` item (on the same level like `caption`), you would add an image of an image, which is probably not what you want. -- With "at the same level", do you mean the properties listed in the table? It only means which properties this type may have.

Comment: Can you say how would it be with all the code I give as example, please?

Comment: @Nrc: Where I placed the comments `<!-- Article properties here -->`, you can place your other properties that belong to the `Article`: `headline`/`name`, `datePublished`, `articleBody`.

Comment: Where do you put <img src="1.png"> should it have an itemprop?

Comment: @Nrc: The `img` should get an `itemprop`, yes (otherwise it would not be recognized by Microdata parsers). Use the [`contentUrl` property](http://schema.org/contentUrl): `<img itemprop="contentUrl" src="1.png" alt="" />`. It must be placed inside of the `ImageObject` item.